# Resource from DLL in other assembly

Tags: xaml, dll, binding, resources

I'm creating an application that will be build in modules (`DLL's`). One of these DLL's provides the `Strings` for the application in different languages.

The DLL has following structure:

- **Languages** (This is the project.)

  - Properties
  - References
  - Language.cs (Here I'm able to set the desired language from the application and has a `GetText` function that returns the `String` based on the set `Culture`.) *Please let me know is this is a good approach.*
  - Language.en-US.resx
  - Language.nl-BE.resx

So, from `Languages.cs` I'm able to get the desired `String` in `C#` from the resource files based on the set `Culture`.

Here is an example:

1. I set the culture to Dutch: `Languages.Language.SetCulture("nl-BE");`
2. I request the Dutch word for the resource `Name`: Language.GetText("Name");
3. It will return the `String` **`Naam`**.

That was `C#`. `Xaml` appears to be a bigger problem to get a `Label.Text` get the resource `Name`.

I added `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:My.Languages.;assembly=My.Languages"` to my `xaml` file, but this is as far as I got. I can't figure out a way how to have a similar `Language.GetText("Name")` in `Binding`.

My only solution at this point would be to bind every `Label.Text` to a property in my `C#` code and get the correct `String` from there. This will generate a lot of "not needed" binding/properties and would be hard to maintain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach for Xaml would be to use a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would call your Language.GetText(key);

e.g. XAML

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding FallbackValue='Naam', ConverterParameter='Name' Converter={StaticResource Translate}}" />
```

C#

```
public class TranslateConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

      string localizedValue = string.Empty;
      if (parameter is string)
      {
         localizedValue = Language.GetText(parameter as string);
         return localizedValue;
      }
      else
      {
         return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool` isn't recognized, so I just removed it. I also had to add the `ConvertBack` method in order to have no errors anymore. I just placed this in the code behind file and it's working like a charm. Tnx.

Comment: DesignerProperties needs "using System.ComponentModel;". I recommend keeping it in.

Comment: I tried that before posting my first comment, but I get this error: `'System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties' does not contain a definition for 'IsInDesignTool'`

Comment: [It](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be in System.Windows.dll or PresentationFramework.dll, make sure you have those References in your project

Comment: My bad, I think I referenced the Silverlight, I think it is call IsInDesignMode now

Comment: I'll have a look into it ;) the solution works like a charm except, some odd behavior for my own UserControl, the WatermarkTextBox. I opened a new topic, maybe you could have a look into it as well? This is the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212371/cant-find-file-with-usercontrol-but-not-in-this-case-label. Your approach works for the Content of the Label, but not for the Watermark Dependency Property of my WatermarkTextBox.

Comment: I updated the answer. `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode` has to be `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())`. This works like a charm and the designer is working.