# Can't find file with UserControl but not (in this case) Label

Tags: wpf, dll, user-controls, file-not-found

I have a UserControl in a the DLL `Controls`, a converter in the DLL `Base` and language resources in the DLL `Languages`.

When I combine everything the following way, everything works fine:

```
<Label Content="{Binding FallbackValue='[Design] Name', ConverterParameter='Name', Converter={StaticResource Translate}}"
           ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"/>
```

No errors and when I run my application the correct word for the parameter `Name` is loaded (in my case Naam for Dutch).

I also try this on my `WatermarkTextBox` like this:

```
<c:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="{Binding FallbackValue='[Design] Name *', ConverterParameter='Name', Converter={StaticResource Translate}}" />
```

But then I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:...\Languages.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why does this happen with my `WatermarkTextBox` in `Controls` DLL and not with the `Label`?

Comment: See my edit for the last guess ;)

Comment: I assume you mean something like this `ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Noru.Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Class Libraries\Noru.Languages\bin\Debug\Noru.Languages.dll"));`? I still get the same error. Could it be because some compile property is set wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step here is to make sure, that the assembly file `Languages.dll` is actually present in the application directory (usually, `bin/Debug/`). If it isn't - as the error message says - the system cannot find the file specified... The solution in this case is to reference the assembly `Languages.dll` in your application project. To avoid this, make sure that every time you add a reference to an assembly, you also add references to this assembly's dependencies. I.e. if you have an application project `App` which references a library `LibA.dll` and `LibA` references a library `LibB.dll`, you should add a reference to `LibB.dll` in your `App` project as well. That way, all required assemblies will always be copied to the output directory.

If the assembly is correctly located in the output directory, but you still get the error message, in 99% of the cases the problem is a mismatch in the building targets, alas the platform for which the assemblies were built. Make sure all projects target the same platform (x86, for example). You can check the target in the projects *Properties* tabs.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I just now understood you're talking about the design time error in Visual Studio's XAML Designer :) The issue is the name of the assembly: `Noru.Languages.dll`. I suppose, the ending `.Languages` is considered a resource name and Visual Studio prohibits resource names in assembly names. There's a registry entry `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designers\AllowResourcesInFilename`, maybe experimenting with that can resolve the issue. Not 100% sure, though. Anyway, if you rename the assembly to `Nori.Language.dll` in the project's properties and rebuild everything, design time support is back and the controls show up correctly in the designer.

**EDIT 2:**

Really strange behavior altogether... Well, this line in the Class `Language` might very well be the cause? Try specifying the full string here... Does this work?

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Noru.Languages.Language", System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Noru.Languages.dll"));
```

**EDIT 3:**

Obviously, the problem was the line I mentioned above in Edit 2. I've experimented a bit:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will return the requested text in the language the application is in. Case sensitive.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">Provide a listed String from the language files.</param>
/// <returns>Will return a System.String in the language of the application.</returns>
public static string GetText(string s)
{
    //return Culture.ToString();
    //return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
    //ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Noru.Lang.Resource1", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Language)));
    //ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(Culture, true, true);

    var rs = LanguageResource.ResourceManager;
    try
    {
        return rs.GetString(s);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

The last version (not commented out) works, because I've generated code for the resource files by setting `AccessModifier` to public in the resource editor (double click on the resource file, you'll find it in the toolbar).

This version (never mind about the resource name, I tried different versions here):

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Noru.Lang.Resource1", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Language)));
```

threw another error, saying it cannot find the resource inside the assembly. I think there was something wrong about the usage of `ResourceManager` here. I'm not an expert here, so I can't tell why. I just know that the last version seems to work as expected... I hope, you'll find the same ;)

Comment: What I found is that the location where `Languages.dll` is looked for is wrong. The full path is `Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Class Libraries\Languages.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`. What I think is that it should look in `...\Class Libraries\Languages\bin\Debug` or `...\Class Libraries\Controls\bin\Debug`. At these 2 locations the `Language.dll` is present. `Class Libraries` is the solution name, `Languages` or `Controls` are the project names in the solution.

Comment: The assembly needs to be located inside the folder which also holds the executable. Is `Languages.dll` located in this folder? Which is the startup project of your solution? Does the startup project reference `Languages.dll`?

Comment: So, `Languages.dll` is used in `Controls.dll`. `Controls.dll` is the location I'm working. `Controls\bin\Debug` has the `Languages.dll`. `Controls.dll` does have a reference to `Languages.dll`. The odd thing is that it works for the `Content` of a `Label`, but not for a DP (`Watermark`) of my own control (`WatermarkTextBox`). The 2 lines of code in my original post are in the same `CustomerView.xaml` file. `WatermarkTextBox` is coded in `Controls.dll`.

Comment: You're right, it's strange that it works with a normal label... Still, it only matters whether the assemblies are in your *application directory*. The output directories of the other projects are not relevant. Have you checked the bin/Debug folder of the **startup project**?

Comment: The startup project has the `Languages.dll` in its `bin/Debug`. The strange thing is that everything compiles correct and works like intended.

Comment: I tried something new, I placed the file in the location it said it can't be found, but still gives the error.

Comment: If you can create a sample project, I'll have a look at it?

Comment: Is there a way to send you the zip to you in private?

Comment: Sent you a mail, hopefully you received it.

Comment: I did, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I've looked at the solution and everything compiles and runs fine. Are you talking about a runtime error or a design time error in the XAML Designer of Visual Studio?

Comment: Ok, this would have been an interesting info ;) I found the issue and will update my answer

Comment: I changed the name from `Noru.Languages.dll` to `Noru.Language.dll` and also in the assembly itself but I still get the same error, now it's just saying `Noru.Language.dll` that can't be found in the same location.